# Replace string pattern containing scores and underscores, problem with capturing

Tags: regex, sed

Good day everyone!

I'm loosing my mind trying to use `sed` for replacing a string pattern.
I have searched old threads about `sed` and escaping special characters, but I still can't get it done. I think my mind is now too deep into wanting to convolute the problem more than necessary too see the easy way.

I have a `.tsv` document, in which the second column represents tag-annotations that come in the form of these possibilities:

```
B-something
B-something-something
B-something_something
B-something-something_something
I-something
I-something-something
I-something_something
I-something-something_something
```

I need to change all the B-*s with B, and the same with the I-*s -> I.

I know I could make it in Python, but I need to learn `sed` for future quick pre-processing.

I played with [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and the pattern that seems to work is the following:

`\b([BI]-[a-zA-Z_-]+)\b`

Using `sed`, I could capture the first part, i.e. 'B-first_character' by using:
`sed /s/\([BI]-[a-zA-Z]\)/replacing_word/g' input > output`

Nothing is replaced when I use:
`sed /s/\([BI]-\)\([a-zA-Z_-]+\)/replacing_word/g'`

Probably the last piece of code is a horrible mistake in my mistakes, my mind is a bit blurry now.
Sorry for the stupid topic and thanks all.

Comment: Please post expected output too in your post for more clarity.

Comment: `+` is a literal `+` in a BRE POSIX pattern. Use `-E` or replace `+` with `\{1,\}` Replace with `\1`. Try `LC_ALL=C sed 's/\([BI]\)-[a-zA-Z_-]\{1,\}/\1/g' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sed command is corrupt: you can't use `/` before the `s` substitution command here as you meant to just use it inside single quotes.

Also, `+` is a literal `+` in a BRE POSIX pattern. Use `-E` or replace `+` with `\{1,\}`.

To restore the captured value use a `\NUMBER` in the replacement pattern.

You may  use

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/\([BI]\)-[a-zA-Z_-]\{1,\}/\1/g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/0lOtrj).

The `LC_ALL=C` will make all character classes behave the same way as at regex101.com.

**Pattern details**

- `\([BI]\)` - Group 1: `B` or `I`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[a-zA-Z_-]\{1,\}` - one or more ASCII letters, `_` or `-` chars.

Comment: I love you. Thanks for the awesome reply and the help. Yes, the sed command was corrupt at the beginning, I wrote it badly in here.